# how to suppress Firefox addon updates window from being on top of everything?

Tags: mac, firefox, firefox-extensions

Whenever Firefox installs updates, the "Firefox addon updates" window is always on top of everything (highest in the z-order of all windows of all apps). Although it lasts only 10-ish seconds, it is very annoying (and unnecessary). Is there a way to suppress that? Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You can disable automatic updates for add-ons from within FireFox.

If you're using FireFox on Windows, navigate to...
Tools > Options... > Advanced > Update > Automatically check updates to:
... and uncheck 'Add-ons'

For FireFox on Linux, navigate to...
Edit > Preferences > Advanced > Update > Automatically check updates to:
... and uncheck 'Add-ons

You can then manually check for updates at a more convenient time by selecting:
Tools > Add-ons > Extensions > Find Updates